# React/CSS: Dynamically updating className of table row works only randomly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to update the style of  table row in the render() function of my component. The style shall change based on the current Selection:

```
this.props.process.modules.map((thisModule,index) => {
    return <tr className={this.classNameForRow(index)} onClick={()=>{this.selectModule(index)}
(...)
```

the `onClick` changes the state of my Component to the selected Module:

```
selectModule = (index) =>{
    let mod = this.props.process.modules[index];
    this.setState({selectedModule:mod});
}
```

the classNameForRow() function returns the style based on the current selection:

```
classNameForRow = (index) =>{
    let mod = this.props.process.modules[index];
    let name = "tr-standard";

    if (this.state.selectedModule === mod) {
        name ="tr-selected"
    }

    if (this.state.selectedModule.nextModuleID === mod.identifier) {
        name ="tr-successor"
    }

    return name;
}
```

When I put console.log the correct classNames will be returned. For some rows the code ist working and marks the selectedRow as well as the row that shows the module with id === nextModuleID (basically the successor of the selected Module). But the browser is not rendering the css class that is returned from classNameForRow() for random rows. I'm new to JS and React but this "behavior" is strange. Does Anybody have an idea?

**Full Code**

```
import React, { Component, useState,setState,useEffect } from 'react'
import './ModulesTable.css'

export class ModulesTable extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedModule : {}
        };
        

    }


    selectModule = (index) =>{
        console.log("BEFORE: " + this.state.selectedModule.identifier);
        let mod = this.props.process.modules[index];
        console.log("MOD: " + mod.identifier)
        this.setState({selectedModule:mod});
        console.log("AFTER: " + this.state.selectedModule.identifier);
    }
    

        classNameForRow = (index) =>{
            
            let mod = this.props.process.modules[index];
            let name = "tr-standard";

            if (this.state.selectedModule.identifier === mod.identifier) {
                name ="tr-selected";
            }

            if (this.state.selectedModule.nextModuleID === mod.identifier) {
                name ="tr-successor";
            }
            console.log(index + ": " + name);
            return name;
        }


    render() {
        
        return (
            <>
            <table className="mainTable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>ID</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Name</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Type</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Successor</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Alternative Successor</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Steps</label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        this.props.process.modules.length > 0
                        ?this.props.process.modules.map((thisModule,index) =>{
                            const myClassName = this.classNameForRow(index);
                            return <tr className={myClassName} onClick={()=>{this.selectModule(index)}} key={index}>
                                <td>
                                    {thisModule.identifier}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {thisModule.name}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {thisModule.moduleType}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {thisModule.nextModuleID}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    {thisModule.altModuleID}
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <button>Edit</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        })
                        : null
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
            {
                
                <div>
                {
                    this.props.process.modules.length === 0
                    ?<label>This Process does not have any modules</label>
                    :<label>{this.props.process.modules.length} Module </label>
                }
                </div>
            }
            <div className="infoBar">
                <div className="color-box-successor"></div>
                </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default ModulesTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved: there were conflicting CSS Styles which randomly overwrote the style used by the table row.

Answer (score 0):

Its quite hard to tell what's going on with the snippets you have provided.  The only potential I can see is that the check -

```
if (this.state.selectedModule === mod) {
   name ="tr-selected"
}
```

may never be returning true, as I suspect `selectedModule` and `mod` are objects with different references, whereas the other `if` condition is checking ids, which I would assume are primitives, e.g. a String.

Try something like -

```
if (this.state.selectedModule.id === mod.identifier)...
```

Comment: you're right -> it is in fact cleaner to compare the identifiers, but this is not the issue here. I get the correct classnames but it just randomly does not render the correct class. I also added the full code